# How to create a download link for an AWS mp4 target link

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, download, mp4

Looking for a way to create a download link or button for an mp4 file hosted on AWS s3.

Here is an example link: http://s3.amazonaws.com/leccap.engin.umich.edu/media/qgf2iui48mu9ib6pbq5/1483652286-726-O-c23-12.mp4

If I have a basic anchor element, I can do this by clicking while holding the alt/option key. e.g.:

```
<a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/file.mp4" download>Download</a>
```

I want to be able to do this with a single click, without having to hold down a key.

I've tried all sorts of Javascript tricks, but everything redirects me directly to the video page.

[This article](https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/1172-how-do-i-force-files-to-download-in-amazon-s3) is relevant, but not helpful since the AWS account is not under my control.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the article. It actually helped me.

Comment: The `download` attribute only works for same-origin URLs. So if the href is not the same origin as the site, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work, I just Checked

```
<form method="get" action="filelink.mp4">
    <button type="submit">Download!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: <a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/file.mp4" download>Download</a>   This works too, I don't know, the link you're inserting in anchor tag, but when i see in my link, it has region at start https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/filname.mp4

Comment: I still have to hold down the option key for that to work. I think my question was worded poorly so I updated it. Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: Have you tried the above solution, In windows I don't need to hold down the alt Key